# Can't send images to gmail through PHPMailer

Tags: php, gmail, phpmailer

I'm using PHPMailer to send some messages in my intranet, the problem occurs when I try to send images in the body of the email, if I just send the images as an attachment everything goes smoothly, but when I try to send the images in the body of the mail Gmail (and just Gmail) ignores the image, even though it shows the message.

[The one in the right is gmail, and the blacked out thing is the company logo, added through the AddEmbeddedImage() function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IO8hf.png)

Even stranger is that I send an embedded image to header of the mail, and this one shows normally.

What can I do so that the images appear?

This is the code:

```
public function enviaEmail($email = "", $subject, $body, $nomes_anexos, $tipo_noticia = false) {

        global $config;

        if($tipo_noticia && ($tipo_noticia == 'company' || $tipo_noticia == 'company')){
            $this->mail->FromName = $config['email_fromname_company'];
        } else {
            $this->mail->FromName = $config['email_fromname'];
        }

        $this->mail->From = $config['email_from'];

        $header = $this->includeHeader($subject);
        $footer = $this->includeFooter();

        if(empty($email)){
            $this->logger->log("Email em branco.");
            return false;
        }

        $this->mail->ClearAllRecipients();
        $this->mail->AddAddress($email);
        $this->mail->Subject = $subject;
        $this->mail->Body    = $header.$body.$footer;
        $this->mail->AltBody = strip_tags($body).$footer;


        //THIS WORKS
        if($tipo_noticia && ($tipo_noticia == 'company' || $tipo_noticia == 'mensagem_company')){
            $this->mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../public/img/company.png', 'logo', 'company.png'); 
        } else {
            $this->mail->AddEmbeddedImage(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../public/img/logo_local_novo.png', 'logo', 'local.png');
        }



        if(!empty($nomes_anexos)){
            foreach($nomes_anexos as $an){
                $nome_anexo_final = preg_replace("/^(.*)?-/","", $an);
                $this->mail->AddAttachment(PATH_ANEXOS."/".$an, urldecode($nome_anexo_final));
            }
        }
        if(!$this->mail->Send()) {
            $this->logger->log("Erro ao enviar e-mail '$subject' para '$email': ". $this->mail->ErrorInfo);
            return false;
        }

        return true;

    }
```

Comment: So you say the image doesn’t show when you try to embed it in `$body`, but when you place it in `$header` instead, it does? Well then you should probably show us what exactly these contain.

Comment: The image shows when I use the $this->mail->AddAttachment() function, but when it's added in the body it doesn't

Comment: So show us _how_ you refer it inside the body then.

Comment: I receive the $body trough a form, and the only time I change it is when I do:

$body = str_replace("'", "&lsquo;", $params['body']);

Comment: `AddEmbeddedImage` adds the image data to the mail, so that you can then _refer_ to the image inside your HTML code, to get it displayed in a specific location. If you don’t actually do that … well then you can’t expect to _see_ anything either.

Comment: So why does it shows in other mail providers (Like outlook or zimbra)?

Comment: May be Gmail is blocking the intranet links, but when you send image as attachments the actual file gets sent instead of just a link

Comment: You need to refer to the images from your HTML message body using the `cid` value you passed in to `addEmbededImage`, like this: `<img src="cid:logo" alt="logo">`.